# How long is the wall for the shower

Tags: bathroom, basement, framing, diy-vs-pro

I am doing the framing for my basement for the first time (never done that before)

I have a shower base in the bathroom.

I am going to build a wall at the end of the shower.

I am not sure how long the wall should be?

Can i just make it exact size of the shower base end?

or maybe it has to be longer?

My concern is the shower glass door, i am worried that the I have to extend the wall to fit shower door

Here is a sketch of the problem.

[image]

Here is a link to the shower base i got

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/glacier-bay-48-inch-x-32-inch-acrylic-shower-base-with-left-concealed-drain/1001186706?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D29B_Corporate_GGL_Shopping_PLA_Bath_Bath__PRODUCT_GROUP_pla-297623692937&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAhomtBhDgARIsABcaYykJj9VEj9zpSnx8j4Zy8EMRXdRdC2zf3HM0Zcnpy9z5-2EQzOxJ1WIaAklREALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Always a good idea to have some overhang. Since wood isn't straight, your wall will not be straight. 
You might be able to make it flush at the bottom where the base is, but the top might be out of plumb. In which case you might now be able to install the door. Extend the wall about 2 - 3" to make it look intentional.

Comment: Another option is make it a glass enclosure but that's under the assumption that the wall isn't a plumbing wall.

Comment: @basement_diy no the plumbing is on the opposite wall and it has been done already

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you have a stud in line with the shower door!

Comment: What do the instructions that came with the shower base say? Does it have a curb for the door to sit on that you're including in Option A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show the dimensions of the shower base. Or details such as if it includes the curb or a curb must be built.

With a built in curb the door/s can fit within the short dimension of the base.
Option A

If you need to build a curb then go with option B.

Option B may be a good idea anyway since it provides space for a towel hook and grab bar if needed for the elderly.

In any event ( as mentioned by others), be sure there is sufficient wood structure to mount the door to.

Comment: This is link for the shower base https://www.homedepot.ca/product/glacier-bay-48-inch-x-32-inch-acrylic-shower-base-with-left-concealed-drain/1001186706?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D29B_Corporate_GGL_Shopping_PLA_Bath_Bath__PRODUCT_GROUP_pla-297623692937&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAhomtBhDgARIsABcaYykJj9VEj9zpSnx8j4Zy8EMRXdRdC2zf3HM0Zcnpy9z5-2EQzOxJ1WIaAklREALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: @asmgx,  I personally don't like that base or those like it as the curb is very low and a shower curtain often "blows out" when showering.  That said, you are using a door, so you can align the door with the inner edge of built-in curb.  Your A framing is minimum. B is an option.  With either you need  double or triple studs for mounting a swinging door.  Double is minimum if a bypass is used.